# Por qué la data que recupero del storage se mete toda en una sola línea de la tabla?

Tags: javascript, html, json, table, storage

Estoy practicando javascript y logro hacer que cada vez que el formulario se envíe, se cree una nueva linea en la tabla como esperado, pero, al remover un linea y recargar el storage, todas las líneas se hacen una sola. Qué le falta a mi código?
Este código lo cree en base a una app de crear tasks y usa la misma lógica. Ya probé con poner los `<td>` adentro de nuevos `<tr>` pero no funciona. Aparentemente, el storage está ignorando el foreach y haciendo que el stringfy del JSON se lea como un solo array.
https://github.com/abneralbino/interactuandoConHTML

```
    let posiciones = [];
    
    reqForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
    
        const form = new FormData(reqForm);
        const tituloDeLaPosicion = form.get('tituloDeLaPosicion');
        const idDeLaPosicion = idGenerator();
        const fechaLimite = new Date(form.get('fechaLimite'));
        const fechaLimiteReal = fechaLimite.toLocaleString(fechaLimite.DATE_SHORT);
        const vacantes = form.get('vacantes');
        const cantDias = (calcularFechas (fechaLimite, fechaDeHoy));
        const categorias = form.get('categoria');
    
    
        const req = {
            titulo: tituloDeLaPosicion,
            id: idDeLaPosicion,
            fecha: fechaLimiteReal,
            rowCantDias: cantDias,
            vacantesReq: vacantes,
            categoria: categorias,
    
        };
    
        crearReq(req);
    });
    
    const crearReq = (req) => {
        const reqsAbiertas = document.getElementById('posicionesAbiertas');
        const tr = document.createElement('tr');
        posiciones.push(req);
    
        tr.innerHTML += `
        <tr>
        <td> ${req.titulo} </td>
        <td> ${req.id} </td>
        <td> ${req.fecha} </td>
        <td> ${req.rowCantDias} </td>
        <td> ${req.vacantesReq} </td>
        <td> ${req.categoria} </td>
        <button class="visualizar"> Ver detalles </button> 
        <button class="remover" id="${req.id}" name="remover" value="${req.id}"> Remover </button>
        </tr>    
        `;
        reqsAbiertas.appendChild(tr);
    
    guardarReqStorage(posiciones);
    
    reqsAbiertas.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        removerReq(e.target.value);
        });
    };
    
    const removerReq = (idPosicion) => {
        posiciones.forEach((req, index) => {
            if (req.id == idPosicion) {
                posiciones.splice(index, 1);
            }
            
        });
        mostrarReqs (posiciones);
        guardarReqStorage (posiciones);
        
    };
    
    const mostrarReqs = (posiciones) => {
        const reqsAbiertas = document.getElementById('posicionesAbiertas');
        const tr = document.createElement('tr');
        
        reqsAbiertas.innerHTML = ''; 
    
        posiciones.forEach(req => {
            tr.innerHTML += `   
            <tr>
            <tr>
                <td> ${req.titulo} </td>
                <td> ${req.id} </td>
                <td> ${req.fecha} </td>
                <td> ${req.rowCantDias} </td>
                <td> ${req.vacantesReq} </td>
                <td> ${req.categoria} </td>
                <button class="visualizar"> Ver detalles </button>
                <button class="remover" id="${req.id}" name="remover" value="${req.id}"> Remover </button>
            </tr>   
            </tr>   
            `; 
                reqsAbiertas.appendChild(tr);
        });  
    
        reqsAbiertas.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            removerReq(e.target.value);
        });
    
    };
    
    
    const guardarReqStorage = (posiciones) => {
        localStorage.setItem('posiciones', JSON.stringify(posiciones));
    };
    
    const getReqStorage = () => {
        const reqStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('posiciones'));
        return reqStorage;
    };
    
    document.addEventListener ('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        if (localStorage.getItem('posiciones')) {
            posiciones = getReqStorage();
            mostrarReqs(posiciones);
        }
    });
```

Y este es el HTML con el form del cual saco la data original que llena el storage y eventualmente llena nuevamente la tabla:

```
<h3 class="fontH3">Datos de la Posición</h3>
    <form class ="form" id="nuevoPuesto">
        <div>
            <label for="Título" class="font">Título de la Posición</label>
            <input type="text" Required placeholder="Título" id="tituloDeLaPosicion" name="tituloDeLaPosicion">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="categoria" class="font" id="categoria">Categoría</label>
            <select id="categoria" name="categoria">
                <option value="Creative & Design">Creative & Design</option>
                <option value="Operations">Operations</option>
                <option value="Finance">Finance</option>
                <option value="Engineering">Engineering</option>
                <option value="Marketing">Marketing</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="Límite" class="font">Fecha Límite de Contratación</label>
            <input type="date" Required placeholder="Fecha límite para que el candidato firme su contrato" id="fechaLimite" name="fechaLimite">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="Vacantes" class="font">Cantidad de vacantes</label>
            <input type="number" Required placeholder="Cuántas personas quiere contratar" id="vacantes" name="vacantes" min="1">
        </div>
        <div class="formFields">
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar" id="enviar">
            <input type="reset" value="Limpiar formulario">
        </div>
    </form>
    <h3 class="fontH3">Posiciones Activas</h3> 
    <table id="posicionesAbiertas" class="font">
        <tr>
        <th>Titulo</th>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Fecha Límite de Contratación</th>
        <th>Días para Presentar Candidatos</th>
        <th>Cantidad de Candidatos a Presentar</th>
        <th>Categoría</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Cuando haces el `posiciones.forEach`...  ¿que es **posiciones**?  No aparece definido previamente.  Y no muestras el código completo, pues aparece indentado y después de `removerReq(e.target.value);});` aparece una llave de cierre de algo que no sabemos lo que es. Tampoco muestras el HTML que se corresponde con el **getElementById**. Recuerda poner un [example] para que podamos ayudarte mejor, gracias.

Comment: @masterguru perdón, es la primera vez que mando una pregunta acá y estoy medio perdido. Por momentos el sitio decia que yo tenia más código que texto. Ahí edito la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

El

```
const tr = document.createElement('tr');
```

estaba duplicando la creación de tr así que moviendolo adentro del forEach resolció el problema.

```
const mostrarReqs = (posiciones) => {
    const reqsAbiertas = document.getElementById('posicionesAbiertas');
    reqsAbiertas.innerHTML = ''; 
    posiciones.forEach(req => {
        const tr = document.createElement('tr');
        tr.innerHTML = `   
        <tr>
            <td> ${req.titulo} </td>
            <td> ${req.id} </td>
            <td> ${req.fecha} </td>
            <td> ${req.rowCantDias} </td>
            <td> ${req.vacantesReq} </td>
            <td> ${req.categoria} </td>
            <button class="visualizar"> Ver detalles </button>
            <button class="remover" id="${req.id}" name="remover" value="${req.id}"> Remover </button>
        </tr>`; 
            reqsAbiertas.appendChild(tr);
    });  

    reqsAbiertas.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        removerReq(e.target.value);
    });

};
```